# Google Maps panTo AND setCenter

Tags: google-maps

The default panTo only pans to the edge of the screen.
I like setCenter but would like to pan to that point. Any ideas welcome

```
   map.setCenter(mymarker.getPoint());

   GEvent.trigger(mymarker,"click"); //open the info window
```

Comment: panTo should pan until the panTo point is at the center of the map. Can you paste some more code that reproduces this behaviour?

Comment: Your right! I set a timeout on the trigger to make sure it centered first!

Code updated above

Comment: Glad you solved it. You may want to post an answer yourself to the question, and accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Fixed Code** - First pan to center then open infowindow after 2 seconds

```
   map.panTo(mymarker.getPosition());

   window.setTimeout(function(){GEvent.trigger(mymarker,"click");},2000);
```